# How to get keycode on `focusout` or `focus` in the input field

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the `focusin` and `focusout` keycode of `tab` and `shift+tab`. but getting only `0` as a value.

how to get the values on `tab` or `shift+tab` on a input field?

here is my try:

```
$('body').on('focusout', '#textbox', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // do your code
    }
    console.log( e.which ); //0
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m09ks06p/8/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have seen, the `focusout` event doesn't expose a `which` attribute in the event object. You'll have to work with the `keydown` event. (You can't use `keyup` because the element loses focus when you press the tab key down, not when you let it up, so your text box doesn't get a `keyup` event when you tab away from it.)

Here's a bit of code that seems to do what you're looking for:

```
var cKey;
var cKeyShifted;
$('body').on('keydown', '#textbox', function(e) {
    cKey = e.which;
    cKeyShifted = e.shiftKey;
});
$('body').on('focusout', '#textbox', function(e) {
    $('#log').html('cKey = ' + cKey + ' ' + cKeyShifted);
    //got to clear the variables, otherwise you can tab out of the box, click
    //back in, click out of it again, and they will not have changed
    cKey = 0; 
    cKeyShifted = false; 
});
```

So, store `e.which` to a variable in the `keydown` event. Then in the `focusout` event, evaluate (and clear) the variable. If it isn't 9, then you didn't use the tab key to lose focus.

Please note that `tab` and `shift+tab` both have the same `e.which` value. You have to evaluate the `shiftKey` attribute of the `keydown` event to determine whether the Shift key was pressed with the Tab key.